# How to change response header (cache) in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

Do you know how to change the response header in CouchDB? Now it has `Cache-control: must-revalidate;` and I want to change it to `no-cache`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any way to configure CouchDB's cache header behavior in its [configuration documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/config/) for general (built-in) API calls. Since this is not a typical need, lack of configuration for this does not surprise me.

Likewise, [last I tried](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1422) even show and list functions (which do give custom developer-provided functions some control over headers) do not really leave the cache headers under developer control either.

However, if you are hosting your CouchDB instance behind a reverse proxy like nginx, you could probably override the headers at that level. Another option would be to add the usual "cache busting" hack of adding a random query parameter in the code accessing your server. This is sometimes necessary in the case of [broken client cache implementations](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-257) but is not typical.

But taking a step back: why do you want to make responses `no-cache` instead of `must-revalidate`? I could see perhaps occasionally wanting to override in the other direction, letting clients cache documents for a little while without *having to* revalidate. Not letting clients cache at all seems a little curious to me, since the built-in CouchDB behavior using revalidated Etags should not yield any incorrect data unless the client is broken.